# Do I need private certificate doing https in Android java

Tags: java, android, https, certificate, private

I need to retrive data from a server talking https to my Android App. 
I get the server certificate dynamically like this:

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
store.load(null);
URLConnection uc = new URL("https://duckduckgo.com/").openConnection();
uc.connect();
Certificate certs[] = ((HttpsURLConnection) uc).getServerCertificates();
for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) store.setCertificateEntry("cert_"+ i, certs[i]);
((HttpsURLConnection) uc).disconnect();
```

I have a custom HttpClient:

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
    final KeyStore store;

    public MyHttpClient(KeyStore store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            return new SSLSocketFactory(store);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And retrieves data form the server like this:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity;
URI url = new URI("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+java");
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url );
HttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(store);
httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
```

Is everything I send and receive encrypted?

I was thinking maybe I had to provide the server with my public key?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'private certificate'. Getting the server certificates and storing them into the truststore won't work unless they are already trusted by, i.e. present in, the truststore, which is circular. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking maybe I had to provide the server with my public key?

You're probably referring to [Public Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and if that were the case, then yes, the other party would need to have your public key in order for the response to be encrypted (for you).

But to answer your question: Yes, everything you send and receive (in this context) is encrypted. In the case of `duckduckgo.com`, you're communicating with a public webserver that has its SSL certificate verified so everything should be fine.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1904206/1101070) answer for a brief overview of how certificate authorities and SSL actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No you don't need a cert to communicate with a server securely.

Long answer: The whole point of certificates is so a client and server can agree on a private encryption key without someone else knowing what that key is. The server certificate will have been issued by some major certificate authority (Verisign, etc.).  You can check the authority to make sure they have actually issued a certificate to the domain name in question.  Once you have verified the cert against the authority you can use the public encryption key from the cert and only the owner of the cert will be able to decrypt whatever it is you encrypt.  In the case of SSL you use the public key on the cert to encrypt a session encryption key you will use to communicate securely with the server.

**When doing this stuff do not omit validating the cert before using it!!!**

Comment: I was planning to omit the validation because I will have full control of the server myself. By getting the certificate dynamically i dont need to preload the certificate in the phone's keystore. The only point (as I see it) with the certificates is to ensure encryption

Comment: The client does not generate the session key; does not encrypt it; and does not send it. It is negotiated via a key agreement protocol.